# Debian 9.3, PHP 7.2, Nginx подключить sqlsrv для MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, debian, pdo, php7

Настроил сервер, все работает.
Необходимо из php подключаться к БД MSSQL. Для этого нужно поставить sqlsrv.

Сделал по инструкциям из гугла.
При выполнении скрипта получаю ошибку:

> `SQLSTATE[01000]: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib
>   '/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.1.so.9.2' : file not
>   found`

Данный файл находится по указанному пути.

Скрипт для теста:

```
<?php
    $opt = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    try {
       $db = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=IP_ADDRESS;Database=DB_NAME", "USER", "PASSWORD"); 
    } catch (PDOException $err) { 
        die('Подключение не удалось: ' . $err->getMessage()); 
    };
```

Comment: права на чтение и выполнение этого файла есть у процесса?

Comment: @teran права есть, вроде как. Так ошибка не на права, а на то что файл не находит.

Comment: ну вы же утверждаете, что файл существует. вот я и предлагаю варианты, которые потенциально могут привести к подобному сообщению об ошибке

Comment: какие права должны быть и кто владелец?

Comment: чтобы у апача было `+rx`, наверное , кто владелец не важно. я в линуксах особо не шарю. лучше, дважды проверьте, что файл и правда существует, и нигде никакая буква вдруг не пропущена.

Comment: точно существует, проверил по буквам, права выставил все для всех. Not found